# discord js, deafen a mentioned user

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm probably misunderstanding exactly what's being returned by the `members` object here, but I'm attempting to test a `deafen` command within my bot - the documentation for discord.js states that the `Message` object contains a `Mentions` property that holds all the valid mentions within a sent message, from there, I can drill down a bit further and get to the `Members` property from within `Mentions` - which returns a collection of `GuildMembers` that have been mentioned in the message - which is what I want. The problems arises when I attempt to grab those `GuildMember` objects from within the collection that I get back - I'm not quite sure what I'm doing wrong, but I get back errors.  The code I have is as follows:

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'deafen',
    cooldown: 5,
    description: 'Deafens mentioned user or users.',
    args: true,
    execute(message) {
        const taggedMembers = message.mentions.members;

        for(const member of taggedMembers) {
            member.setDeaf(true)
                .then(() => console.log(`Deafened ${member.displayName}`))
                .catch(console.error);
        }
    },
};
```

and I get back this error in my terminal window:

```
TypeError: member.setDeaf is not a function 
    at Object.execute (/home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/commands/admin/deafen.js:10:20)
    at Client.<anonymous> (/home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/FutabaBot.js:80:17)
    at Client.emit (events.js:210:5)
    at MessageCreateHandler.handle (/home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/packets/handlers/MessageCreate.js:9:34)     
    at WebSocketPacketManager.handle (/home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/packets/WebSocketPacketManager.js:105:65) 
    at WebSocketConnection.onPacket (/home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketConnection.js:333:35)
    at WebSocketConnection.onMessage (/home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketConnection.js:296:17)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (/home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/ws/lib/event-target.js:120:16)
    at WebSocket.emit (events.js:210:5)
    at Receiver.receiverOnMessage (/home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/ws/lib/websocket.js:789:20)
```

I'm not sure if it's necessary, but I can post the other pieces of code that relate to this - and the documentation for discord.js can be found [here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/general/welcome)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `message.mentions.members` returns a [Collection of GuildMembers and a Snowflake (some unique identifier](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageMentions?scrollTo=members). A Collection is an extension of the [Map class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map), where a map is an array with each item having a key and a value attribute.

When looping over a map, like you're doing with `for(const member of taggedMembers)`, each item (or `member` in your case) is a key and a value pair. Then you're trying to call the `setDeaf` method on that pair, which as you've seen doesn't work.

What you want is to only loop over the values in the collection. This can easily be done with a `.forEach`. I'll add some example code down below:

```js
taggedMembers.forEach((member) => {
    member.setDeaf(true)
        .then(() => console.log(`Deafened ${member.displayName}`))
        .catch(console.error);
});
```

Give it a go and let me know if you run into any more issues.

**EDIT:** As [slothiful](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11321804/slothiful) pointed out in the comments, using a `.forEach` won't catch any Promise rejections even after attaching a `.catch()`. To fix this you can use the `for ... of` loop but destructuring the pair. This can be seen in the example below:

```js
for (let [, member] of taggedMembers) {
    member.setDeaf(true)
        .then(() => console.log(`Deafened ${member.displayName}`))
        .catch(console.error);
}
```

Comment: Yep! this did it! I managed to figure it out last night after doing a bunch of inspecting to see what `member` actually contained but yeah, a `forEach` was what I needed over a `for...of`. Thanks!

Comment: You can still use a `for...of` loop, but with a [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment). `for (let [, member] of taggedMembers)`. Promise rejections in a `forEach()` loop will **not** be caught, even after attaching a `catch()` method, due to the fact that it simply calls promises and moves on.

Comment: @slothiful I didn't know that, I have added your comment as an edit to the answer. Thanks!